# Why does my WeakReference gets NULL inside my AsyncTask?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

I have spent a lot of hours trying to reproduce and understand the cause of this problem, with no success in either of these goals.

I have tried to leave only the code related to the problem, but I believe a few minutes are still necessary to understand the problem and context. I hope that someone will be able to spot the problem in my implementation or at least help me understand the cause.

**Description of the application:**

Word game where you play against the computer. After the computer has laid a word on the board, the definition of this word is fetched online in an `AsyncTask` and displayed in a `TextView`

**How I discovered the issue:**

1. I use [ACRA](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGwQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/acra/&ei=tlfbT5PkPIqZ8QOzsa2xCw&usg=AFQjCNF1L9fawVNYyKuqqIa7q22TBcL08w&sig2=fyVkGVNNS9DcOUY4CnEWjA) for crash and error reporting (great free tool by the way). It sends me reports for each unexpected situtation (this one does not lead to a crash). I have been receiving many reports of **errors 1,2,3 and 4** (see code)
2. Some bad reviews on Google Play tend to show that some users do not see the definition even though they are connected to Internet. (I am pretty sure this functional bug is related to the previously mentioned errors, though I cannot prove it)

**A word on the code design:**

After reading a lot on memory leaks in Android, I have decided to make the AsyncTask that retrieves the definition online a **static inner class** (even though my main activty currently does not support rotations, which are the main causes of leaks: I put in my Manifest `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`).

I need access to the parent `Activity` from this `AsyncTask` because I retrieve strings from the resources, and perform some changes on the UI in `onPostExecute()`.
Hence, I use a `WeakReference` in the `AsyncTask` which is pointing to the parent `Activity`. This should prevent memory leaks in case the `Activity is recreated or killed while the`AsyncTask` is still running.

**What exactly is the problem:**

- The `WeakReference` or the return of its `get()` method is `null` in
  some unexplained situations (I suspect it impacts more than 1% of the games or
  players) (see code)
- All kinds of devices and Android versions are impacted, and I often see several occurences coming from the same device)
- I have never been able to reproduce these errors (the most obvious try was exiting the activity while the definition is being downloaded, but this didn't cause any error)

**Meaningful parts of my code:**

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView _definition; //inflated from XML in onCreate()
    private ProgressDialog _pDialog; //created in onCreate()

    private Handler _handlerToDelayDroidMove = new Handler();
    private Handler _handlerToDelayProgressDialog = new Handler();
    private Handler _handlerToDelayDefinitionClosure = new Handler();

    public void onClickValidatePlayerMoveAndTriggerDroidMove(View v) {
        int score = _arbitre.validatePlayerMoveAndReturnScore(_listOfLetters);
        toast(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.player_word_score), score));

        // ***** Only start Droid move when previous toast has been displayed ****
        timedDroidPlayWithSpinner();
    }

    private void timedDroidPlayWithSpinner() {
        _handlerToDelayProgressDialog.removeCallbacks(_droidThinkingDialogRunnable);
        _handlerToDelayDroidMove.removeCallbacks(_droidPlayRunnable);

        _handlerToDelayProgressDialog.postDelayed(_droidThinkingDialogRunnable, 1500);
        _handlerToDelayDroidMove.postDelayed(_droidPlayRunnable, 1500 + DUMMY_DELAY);
    }

    private Runnable _droidThinkingDialogRunnable = new Runnable() { //Show a "Droid is thinking spinner dialog"
        public void run() {
            _pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            _pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.droid_thinking));
            _pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            _pDialog.show();
        }
    };

    private Runnable _droidPlayRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String word = playBestMoveAndUpdateGUI(); // Droid move (CPU intensive, can take several seconds)
            saveGameStateToPrefs();

            _pDialog.dismiss(); //Hide "Thinking dialog")
            new SearchDefinitionTask(GameActivity.this).execute(word);
        }
    };

    private Runnable _hideDefinitionRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            _definition.startAnimation(_slideUpAnim);
            _definition.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };

    // Made static so we are sure if does not reference the Activity (risk of leak)
    public static class SearchDefinitionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
        private WeakReference<GameActivity> weakRefToGameActivity;

        public SearchDefinitionTask(GameActivity context) { //Save a weak reference to the Activity
            super();
            weakRefToGameActivity = new WeakReference<GameActivity>(context);
        }

        protected String[] doInBackground(String... words) {
            try {
                DefFetcherInterface defFetcher = null;
                Language l = weakRefToGameActivity.get()._dictionaryId;
                defFetcher = new OnlineDefinitionFetcher(l);
                return defFetcher.getDefinition(words[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) { // Typical exceptions are due to lack of internet connectivity
                Log.e("Definition fetch error: ", e.toString());
                String[] ret = { "", "" };
                ret[0] = mots[0];
                if (weakRefToGameActivity == null) { // !!! This occurs in ~0.3% of the games !!!
                    ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleSilentException(new Exception("Silent ERROR 1: weakRef is NULL"));
                    return ret;
                }
                if (weakRefToGameActivity.get() == null) { !!! This occurs in ~1% of the games !!!
                    ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleSilentException(new Exception("Silent ERROR 2: weakRef.get() is NULL"));
                    return ret;
                }

                // If we get here we still have a reference on our Activit/context, so let's show a decent error message
                ret[1] = weakRefToGameActivity.get().getResources().getString(R.string.no_connection);
                return ret;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            if (result[0] != "") { //Don't send another error report if WeakRef was already NULL in doInBackground()
                if (weakRefToGameActivity == null) { !!! This occurs in ~0.5% of the games !!!
                    ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleSilentException(new Exception("Silent ERROR 3: weakRef is NULL"));
                } else if (weakRefToGameActivity.get() == null) { !!!!!!!! This occurs in ~1% of the games !!!!!!!!
                    ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleSilentException(new Exception("Silent ERROR 4: weakRef.get() is NULL"));
                } else {
                    // Everything is fine, show a box with the definition of the word for a few seconds 
                    //(with animation to make the box appearing from the top of the screen)
                    weakRefToGameActivity.get()._definition.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    weakRefToGameActivity.get()._handlerToDelayDefinitionClosure.removeCallbacks(weakRefToGameActivity.get()._hideDefinitionRunnable);
                    weakRefToGameActivity.get()._definition.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + result[0].toUpperCase() + "</b> " + result[1]));

                    weakRefToGameActivity.get()._definition.startAnimation(weakRefToGameActivity.get()._slideDownAnim);
                    weakRefToGameActivity.get()._handlerToDelayDefinitionClosure.postDelayed(weakRefToGameActivity.get()._hideDefinitionRunnable,
                            DURATION_OF_DEFINITION);
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Any idea of what could go wrong or how to reproduce?

Comment: What happens if somebody starts downloading (so a reference to the activity is captured in the async task) then rotates the device (so the activity becomes garbage)? What if garbage collection also happens between the activity becoming garbage and the download completing? Apologies if you already answered these questions.

Comment: @lain I prevent rotations in  my manifest (force portrait). I added the details in the question.

Comment: Did you ever figured this one out?? I want to use a weak reference for an asynktask and found this post. Could changing to a soft reference improve this or using a ghost reference to find out if the reference is GCed??

Comment: @Sébastien, Why did you check `weakRefToGameActivity == null` ? Do you have any theory behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Sebastien, maybe you can try to check the onDestroy is never called for your Activity... The activity can be restarted when the screen is rotated (which you already handle), but there are other configuration changes that may cause the same behavior.

Another pretty common one is to take the keyboard out on some phones, but there are others that are even more obscure to me. You can see the list [there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)

Beside that, I really don't see anything wrong in your code and cannot imagine what else could cause your trouble.

The worst ones are your errors 1 and 3. Can you check in the constructor that weakRefToGameActivity is not null after it is created? (and if it is null, what about the context argument).

Please post updates once you find the root cause of your problem.
Bonne chance.